# insert javascript generated element into primeng turbotable?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I'm replacing a custom made table with PrimeNG's turbotable. I have some buttons I need to insert into the table that call special javascript functions I've written, but I'm stuck on how to insert the element into the table.

It displays as `[object HTMLInputElement]` instead of as a button. I know the code that generates the button is good, because it worked great in the old table set up. I think the problem is the turbotable it turning it into text and I'm not sure how to make it stay HTML.

This is what's displayed.

[image]

Here's the turbotable

```html
              <p-table [columns]="resultsCols" [value]="results">
                <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
                  Agencies  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Count {{results?.length}}
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                  <tr>
                    <th >Options</th>
                    <th [pSortableColumn]="'agency'" >Agency</th>
                    <th [pSortableColumn]="'department'" class="ui-p-2">Department</th>
                    <th [pSortableColumn]="'affiliateCount'" class="ui-p-4">Affiliate Count</th>
                    <th [pSortableColumn]="'basigdate'" class="ui-p-6">BA Sig Date</th>
                  </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-r>
                  <tr>
                    <td>  {{r.btnEdit}}</td>
                    <td >{{r.agency}}</td>
                    <td class="ui-p-2">{{r.department}}</td>
                    <td class="ui-p-4">{{r.affiliateCount}}</td>
                    <td class="ui-p-6">{{r.basigdate}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </ng-template>
              </p-table>
```

Here's how I generate the button and populate the results array

```js
var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

  var inputEdit = document.createElement("input");
  inputEdit.type = "button";
  inputEdit.value = "Edit";
  inputEdit.classList.add("btn-link");
  inputEdit.onclick = (
    function(i) {
      return function() {
        comp.setEditMode(i);
      }
    }
  )(result[i].id);


  var a = new agencySearchResult();
  a.agency = result[i].name;
  a.affiliateCount = result[i].affiliateCount;
  a.basigdate = result[i].baSigDate;
  a.department = result[i].department;
  a.btnEdit = inputEdit;

  comp.results.push(a); 
}
```

Lastly, here's where the `agencySearchResult` is defined in typescript

```js
export class agencySearchResult {
  constructor() {};

  agency: string;
  department: string;
  affiliateCount: string;
  basigdate: string;

  btnEdit: HTMLInputElement;
}
```

I think the problem is the `{{r.btnEdit}}`  line in the HTML, but I included all the relevant stuff just in case.

So Internet, how do you insert a javascript generated HTML element into a turbotable ?

Comment: Why do you create your button in TS instead of in HTML ?

Comment: So I can pass it a complicated onclick function that I can't seem to do with a button generated on the html side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better write your HTML button inside your HTML component file instead of generating it in your TS code.

So I would suggest you to replace

```
<td>  {{r.btnEdit}}</td>
```

and

```
var inputEdit = document.createElement("input");
  inputEdit.type = "button";
  inputEdit.value = "Edit";
  inputEdit.classList.add("btn-link");
  inputEdit.onclick = (
    function(i) {
      return function() {
        comp.setEditMode(i);
      }
    }
  )(result[i].id);
```

with something like

```
<td><input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn-link" (click)="edit(r.id)"/></td>
```

and

```
edit(rowId) {
    alert('Edition of row ' + rowId);
    // do whatever you need
}
```

which is much more concise and readable.

See this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3q4vn)